# How to add multiple classes as selectors to the .on function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if I have below function, but I want to use multiple classes that stored in variables, how to do it the BEST way for .on function. What I did is this,

```
$(document).on('click',class_fbDetailBtn,function(){
        selectedDiv=$(this);
        get_feeback_detail();
    });
```

In above example, I can only assign 1 variable for selector which is `class_fbDetailBtn`

thank you

Comment: Your filters should be a string of selectors, separated by commas. Also, don't use long selectors because this causes performance issues.

Comment: @Robusto, I stored the string in a variable to optmize performance thats the reason you see a variable instead of a string. and thanks for let me konw about the length of varilable, btw, is the result effect so huge on performance for the length I use in above example?

Comment: Interesting...seem ppl dont really want to help one really need help, wonder whoever voted down is for what reason? Or they just think they knows a lot or sth lol smh

Answer (score 2):

You can have a coma seperated list of values in `class_fbDetailBtn`

```
var class_fbDetailBtn = '.class1, .class2'
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KCMrs/)

Answer (score 0):

Example, use a simple object with one param:

```
function myHandler( event ) {
  alert( event.data.foo );
}
$( "p" ).on( "click", { foo: "bar" }, myHandler );
```

Multiples params:

```
$("some selector").click({param1: "Hello", param2: "World"}, cool_function);

function cool_function(event){
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
}
```

Example using clases as Selector type string:

```
$('#div1, #div2').on("click", ".navegar", function (e) {
           ...     
});
```

Comment: Hum...very interesting answer! I like it, i think your parameters can be saved as an array object and use its name as a variable name to do write the same statement I use in the question, right? correct me if I am wrong! Thanks